# Update and Insert based on Oracle APEX item value

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I have APEX page that does updates to a table(SAMPLE_TAB). This table has multiple columns(ID, BADGEID, USERID, NAME, CITY, ZIP, EFTDT, TERMDT, STATUS) ID is distinct number for the records.

BADGEID and USERID are related and if either one record is changed it should automatically create New record and expire old record.

If there is a change in NAME, CITY or ZIP then record update should do.

For Example: See below table

ID  BADGEID  USERID  NAME  CITY   ZIP   EFFDT      TERMDT      STATUS

1   2345     54623   XYZ   NY     00000 8/31/2020  12/31/2199  Active

2   5678     90876   DEF   NJ     00001 8/31/2020  12/31/2199  Active

If BADGEID 2345 is changed to 2354 for same USERID(54623) On SEP 1 2020 Then there should be a
New Record As below

3   2354     54623   XYZ   NY   00000 09/01/2020  12/31/2199 ACTIVE

And update old record to below

1   2345     54623   XYZ   NY   00000 8/31/2020   09/01/2020 INACTIVE

I tried below PL/SQL code in update processing but getting error

DECLARE
ID_PARM = (SELECT BADGEID FROM SAMPLE_TAB WHERE ID = :P1_ID)

BEGIN
IF (:P1_BADGEID = ID_PARM) THEN
UPDATE .......
ELSE
INSERT and UPDATE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this. Fill in the "..." with additional columns/page items/conditions:

```
DECLARE
  l_old_row sample_tab%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO l_old_row FROM sample_tab WHERE id = :P1_ID;
  IF ((l_old_row.badge_id != :P1_BADGE_ID) OR (l_old_row.user_id != :P1_USERID))
  THEN
    UPDATE sample_tab SET status = 'INACTIVE' WHERE id = :P1_ID;
    INSERT INTO sample_tab (badgeid,userid,...) VALUES (:P1_BADGE_ID, :P1_USERID,...);
  ELSIF ((l_old_row.name != :P1_NAME) OR (l_old_row.city != :P1_CITY) OR ...) THEN
    UPDATE sample_tab
       SET name = :P1_NAME,
           city = :P1_CITY,
           ...
     WHERE id = :P1_ID;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I am getting error at the "SELECT * FROM sample_tab INTO l_old_row WHERE id = :P1_ID;" part with SQL Command not properly ended.

Comment: Changes sql statement to below and it worked SELECT * INTO l_old_row  FROM sample_tab WHERE id = :P1_ID;"

Comment: @MHK thanks I have updated my answer - code was untested